# LINQ update procedures - best practice

Tags: performance, linq, linq-to-sql, data-access-layer

What would be considered best practice for updates when using LINQ:

- To have an instantiated db/facade
  object, and submit all changes to a
  record in one go?
- To have a static db/facade object,
  and submit changes cell by cell?

Right now I'm in a project where each cell for a record has its own static update method

```
public static void CellName(int id, int data)
{
     using (var scope = new someDataContext())
     {
          var TableName = scope. CellName.Single(v => v.ID == id);
          TableName.CellName = data;
          scope.SubmitChanges();
     }
}
```

These can then be set as a property in a business object, following the usual `TableName.CellName = [something]` scheme.

But I've also done projects where we've used an instantiated db/facade class. Where you first set the new values like properties and then call a `database.SubmitChanges()` method which then does the update for the entire record (or records).

From a design perspective, I like the first option better - when a property is set, the changes are instantaneous, and it's treated like any other object. But from a technical perspective, I suspect there's performance to be gained by doing updates in bulk.

So which method should I chose - or is there other options I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating invidual cells is extremely inefficient. The main overhead in updating a database is instantiating a connection, sending & receiving a reply, and finding the row to update in the table. If you update per cell then you'll need to perform these steps for every cell - if you update per row then it's once per row.

Updating cells individually is the equivalent of writing SQL like

```
-- new command
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column1] = 'Value1' WHERE [Id] = 1
GO
-- new command
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column2] = 'Value2' WHERE [Id] = 1
GO
-- new command
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column3] = 'Value3' WHERE [Id] = 1
GO
```

where the commands are processed serially, and each command waits until the previous command completes before executing. Whilst this might not be much slower than updating a whole row at a time, it is *likely* to be slower, and is definitely not faster.

The preferred method is to update all the properties at once, and then send a single SQL command.

```
UPDATE [Table] 
SET [Column1] = 'Value1', [Column2] = 'Value2', [Column3] = 'Value3'
WHERE [Id] = 1
```

There are a few steps involved and if you think about it physically and practically it should all make sense.

Firstly, LINQ-to-SQL retrieves the entire row so you can update properties. The 'per cell' or 'per row' operations both need to do this, so it takes the same amount of time.

```
// the "Single" operator retrieves an entire row 
var TableName = scope.CellName.Single(v => v.ID == id);
var row = scope.MyTable.Single(v => v.Id == id); // more accurate description

-- sql looks something like this
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Id] = @id
```

This involves

- compiling a query
- opening a connection / retrieving a connection from the pool
- sending the command to the SQL server
- receiving a reply from the SQL server

Communicating with another server can take anywhere from a few milliseconds up to many seconds, depending on distance, performance, server load, etc.

You then update a property.

```
row.Column1 = data;
```

This takes mere cycles. It is an immeasurably small component of the overall operation time.

And then you submit the changes.

```
scope.SubmitChanges();

-- sql looks like this
UPDATE [MyTable] SET /* set of columns to update */ WHERE [Id] = @id
```

This again involves a number of steps

- compile the query
- sending the command to SQL Server
- receiving the response from SQL Server

There's nothing 'instantaneous' about updating cells individually - the cell will be updated in the same time as a whole row would be updated using the 'per row' pattern. It's just that the remaining cells will take *longer* to be updated.

Not only that, from the look of your question you're also going to have hundreds of boilerplate `UpdateProperty` methods. I've never seen or heard of such a pattern before but to be honest it sounds disasterous - you're sending many times more SQL commands than are necessary, and you're multiplying your database latency by the number of columns in your table.